# Mercury + Mito + jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics

I built a web application via Mercury, which run some script and show tables. But now I need to implement opportunity to edit those tables inside the web app.

I tried a Mito package

```
import mitosheet
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C://Users//USER//Downloads//archive//Iris.csv')
mitosheet.sheet(df, analysis_to_replay="id-sfsxwatuac")
```

But got an error `'CaptureShell' object has no attribute 'kernel'`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 6
      4 df = pd.read_csv('C://Users//USER//Downloads//archive//Iris.csv')
      5 import mitosheet
----> 6 mitosheet.sheet(df, analysis_to_replay="id-sfsxwatuac")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mitosheet\mito_backend.py:448, in sheet(analysis_to_replay, view_df, sheet_functions, importers, editors, *args)
    439     mito_backend = get_mito_backend(
    440         *args, 
    441         analysis_to_replay=analysis_to_replay, 
   (...)
    444         user_defined_editors=editors,
    445     )
    447     # Setup the comm target on this
--> 448     mito_backend = register_comm_target_on_mito_backend(
    449         mito_backend,
    450         comm_target_id
    451     )
    453 except:
    454     log('mitosheet_sheet_call_failed', failed=True)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mitosheet\mito_backend.py:360, in register_comm_target_on_mito_backend(mito_backend, comm_target_id)
    357     comm.send({'echo': open_msg['content']['data']}) # type: ignore
    359 # Register the comm target - so the callback gets called
--> 360 ipython.kernel.comm_manager.register_target(comm_target_id, on_comm_creation)
    362 return mito_backend

AttributeError: 'CaptureShell' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

Is it possible to fix this? And if not, which instruments I can use for running python script and table editing?

Comment: Are you asking how to fix this error or are you asking for recommendations?  If you wish to know the former, please include your code and the full traceback error.  As for the latter, recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue with Mercury.  https://github.com/mljar/mercury/issues/413